# Simple php contact form, but on submit want to keep the validate.check(this) and add window.open

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a simple php contact form whereby i would like any error messages or thank you pages to open in a new window, whilst also keeping the validate.check bit.

Current code looks like:

`<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contactformpost.php" onsubmit="return validate.check(this)">`

Would it be right in coding it like this:

`<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contactformpost.php" onsubmit="return validate.check(this); window.open('','my_form_target', 'width=300,height=200', true)">`

Comment: Try it like so: onsubmit="return (validate.check(this) && window.open('','my_form_target', 'width=300,height=200', true))"
I'm not sure if it will work, so it is a comment :)

Comment: From a UI perspective, I would strongly advice against this. A popupblocker would probably block it. Error message is best shown in the form itself, thank you's on a different page. Also, don't write all this code inline, but in a separate script, and call this with an eventhandler.